# Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment

Tags: unix

I am learning programming in the Unix Environment and hence I downloaded the book Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment Second Edition. However I am not able to find any exercises in it at the end of chapters. Am I missing something very important here? Please excuse me if my question is silly as I am new to programming. I have gone through some of the questions related to this like
[How to Practice Unix Programming in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950256/how-to-practice-unix-programming-in-c)

Comment: not really a question

Comment: The reason for asking the question is because I came across references to exercise while reading the book but I can find none. Hence can someone please confirm

Answer (score 2):

Well, that's an interesting question. The copy I just downloaded has all the exercises at the end of each chapter.

It also has a copyright on it with the following text, so I deleted it straight away:

> Copyright © 2005 Pearson Education, Inc.
>
> All rights reserved. Printed in the United States of America. This publication is protected by copyright, and permission must be obtained from the publisher prior to any prohibited reproduction, storage in a retrieval system, or transmission in any form or by any means, electronic, mechanical, photocopying, recording, or likewise.

Perhaps you might want to reconsider doing this legally <sup>(a)</sup>. I dare say any e-book you got from the publisher (or the dead-tree version) would be more complete than some dodgy, potentially illegal copy downloaded from the net.

I'm also sure at some point, if you're working hard writing software in order to support you and your family, you wouldn't want people violating *your* copyright.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> That's assuming you are not currently doing so. If you are, and your copy of the book is legal, you should contact the publisher rather than asking a question on SO.

Comment: yes I just tried to find a shortcut way but I guess it is pretty unethical on my part so I will address that immediately